# Unable to Connect to Jenkins Server (Amazon Linux AMI)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, installation

When I had installed Jenkins on Amazon Linux AMI following steps mentioned in http://bhargavamin.com/how-to-do/install-jenkins-on-amazon-linux-aws/

After installation I was able to open Jenkins through browser but when I selected option "**Install Plugins**" it showed error as "Unable to connect to Jenkins Server."

So then how to troubleshoot this issue??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is pretty simple, if you do `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080` on your host machine, you should get a message stating:

```
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

This means that jenkins has anonymous priviledges which is not allowing any connection.

To solve this issue, you will have to do two changes:

1. Add Jenkins user to root group: `sudo usermod -a -G root jenkins`
2. Make Jenkins listen to all external IPs by editing file `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and changing the `JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0"`

Once this is done, restart the jenkins server and then try to install plugins for jenkins.

Comment: I do get the first section when running the curl command. but when the `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file doesnt exist on my machine, any ideas?

Comment: @NotSoShabby it changed into `/etc/default/jenkins`

Comment: Thanks, you make my day

Comment: I did the steps above and still having that error

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this trick https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45388 and it works. What I did is add `passwd:` as prefix of file `/var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword` and click `retry` button for several times and finally it works.

Answer (score 0):

Updating java-1.7.0-openjdk to java-1.8.0-openjdk will do the trick and restart the jenkins service or else change the port number and try it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on my ubuntu VPC, here is how I solve `Unable to connect to Jenkins` issue.

In my VPC Nginx is installed. Nginx is listening on port 80 so you need to open the firewall to that port as well.

To open the firewall use the following command:
`sudo ufw allow 80`.

And run this command `sudo ufw status` to verify the firewall is opened for port 80

After that, you can get the default web page for Nginx by using `your_public_ip:80` and Jenkins by entering `your_public_ip:8080`.

Answer (score -2):

1.Click on retry
2.Fill admin user name, pwd ,mail, full name
3.If filled already use pwd given in initialAdminPassword folder
4.proceed